# the best way to set up an event listener in backdraftjs?

Tags: backdraftjs

I want to set up an event listener in a component that will go away when the component is destroyed. Is this the correct way to do that?

```
this.ownWhileRendered(connect(document, 'click', this.handleDocClick.bind(this)));
```

`connect` -> returns a destroyable (https://backdraftjs.org/docs.html#bd-core.functions.connect)

`ownWhileRendered` -> Ensures Destroyable instances are destroyed when the instance is unrendered (https://backdraftjs.org/docs.html#bd-core.classes.Component.ownWhileRendered)

So does that seem correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to make the listener go away:

when the component is **destroyed**, then

```
this.own(
    connect(document, 'click', this.handleDocClick.bind(this)));
```

when the component is **unrendered**, then

```
this.ownWhileRendered(
    connect(document, 'click', this.handleDocClick.bind(this)));
```